# Replace local Project with git

Tags: git, replace, repository, pull

I made some changes in my project, which I don't want to keep. How can I replace the whole project with the one my team-mates uploaded to the GIT server.
I cannot pull, I get this:
 "Pull is not possible because you have unmerged files.
Please, fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm '
as appropriate to mark resolution, or use 'git commit -a'."

The thing is, I don't want to commit any changes I made to the files, because I fear it would overwrite the new features programmed by my team-mates.
I don't need my changes I made to the files uploaded, I just want to have the new ones. 
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4):

To trash your changes that haven't been commited yet, use

```
git reset --hard
```

If you want to save it as a draft using git (not to commit anywhere, but just save it in a safe place to return after some operations), use `git stash`:

```
git stash
... do something on the git tree ...
git stash apply
... your changes is present again
```

Comment: git stash is recommended!  I wouldn't get in the habit of using git reset --hard except in emergencies where nothing else works.  And I'm not sure such emergencies really exist anyway!

Comment: yes, `git reset` is like deleting a file without "Are you sure?" and Recycle Bin.

Comment: Also, consider always developing on a topical branch.  That way you can let master track origin/master without any worries.